SP List Change Events in Event Grid
I recently hooked up Azure Event Grid to a graph partner topic to try and get SP list events on a tenant. I successfully created a subscription and a topic appeared. That said, I could not find a way to enter a resource that would capture all list events. The resource would only take a scoped path:
{
"changeType": "Updated",
"notificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=&resourcegroup=&partnertopic=&location=",
"lifecycleNotificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=&resourcegroup=&partnertopic=&location=",
"resource": "</sites/siteid/lists/listName>",
"expirationDateTime": ,
"clientState": ""
}
Is there a way to capture all list event updates? Not just for one list but for all?

Hi @J_James, Try to create individual subscriptions for each list or at least scope them site by site.


Is there a way to capture all list event updates? Not just for one list but for all?

Unfortunately, the Microsoft Graph API does not support wildcard subscriptions to capture all list events across a tenant or site.

Query all the lists in a site. Create a subscription for each list.

Get all Lists in the Marketing Site:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com:/sites/Marketing/lists
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aDAifQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

Response:
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "a1b2c3d4-e5f6-7890-ab12-34cdef567890",
      "displayName": "Documents"
    },
    {
      "id": "b2c3d4e5-f6a7-8901-b234-56def6789012",
      "displayName": "Tasks"
    }
  ]
}

Now, Create Subscription for List 'Documents'.
API call:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aDAifQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://contoso-event-grid-partner-topic.eastus-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events",
  "resource": "/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com/lists/a1b2c3d4-e5f6-7890-ab12-34cdef567890",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-11-18T00:00:00Z",
  "clientState": "myClientState123"
}

Response:
{
  "id": "sub-docs-1",
  "resource": "/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com/lists/a1b2c3d4-e5f6-7890-ab12-34cdef567890",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-11-18T00:00:00Z",
  "clientState": "myClientState123"
}


Once the subscription is set up, if an item is updated in the Documents list, Azure Event Grid will forward the notification to the partner topic.

Event Grid Payload for Updated List Item:
{
  "id": "event-docs-12345",
  "subject": "/subscriptions/{azure-subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/partnerTopics/{partner-topic}",
  "data": {
    "changeType": "updated",
    "resource": "/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com/lists/a1b2c3d4-e5f6-7890-ab12-34cdef567890/items/1",
    "clientState": "myClientState123"
  },
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Graph.ListItemUpdated",
  "eventTime": "2024-10-18T12:30:45Z",
  "dataVersion": "1.0"
}

log:
[2024-10-18 12:30:45] INFO: Event received from Event Grid for list 'Documents' (list ID: a1b2c3d4-e5f6-7890-ab12-34cdef567890).
[2024-10-18 12:30:46] INFO: Change type: updated. Item ID: 1.


So there is no way to pick up all change events for a site without having to subscribe to each list? Also, for some reason, when a change event occurs, I did not see the actual list item id. This is what I see:

"data": {
"subscriptionId": "XXX",
"clientState": "",
"resource": "/sites/XXX/lists/Results",
"tenantId": "XXX",
"resourceData": {
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.ListItem"
}, NOTE That list item ID is not there like it is in your example

Microsoft Graph currently requires you to subscribe to each list individually; there isn’t a way to set up a wildcard subscription for an entire site to capture all list events.
